# Google Calendar Workspace Add-on function not invoked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/cats-quickstart) to get a Calendar add-on up and running. The functions for Gmail are invoked and working correctly, but the Calendar function is not invoked at all - i.e. I see Executions of `onGmailCompose`, type `Add-on` in the AppsScript editor, but none for `onCalendarEventOpen`. Nothing for Calendar in the Logs Explorer either.

Manifest (`appsscript.json`):

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Cats",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "universalActions": [
        {
          "label": "Learn more about Cataas",
          "openLink": "https://cataas.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
        }
      ],
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [
          {
            "text": "Insert cat",
            "runFunction": "onGmailCompose"
          }
        ],
        "draftAccess": "NONE"
      }
    },
    "drive": {
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
      }
    },
    "calendar": {
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventOpen"
      },
      "eventUpdateTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventUpdate"
      },
      "currentEventAccess": "READ"
    }
  }
}
```

functions:

```js
function onCalendarEventOpen(e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log("CALENDAR-EVENT-OPEN!!!")  
}

function onCalendarEventUpdate(e) {
  console.log("CALENDAR-EVENT-UPDATE!!!")
}
```

Screenshot of Executions tab (only Gmail, nothing for Calendar):
[image: Executions tab]

Screenshot of Logs Explorer (again only Gmail, no logs from attempts to trigger in Calendar)
[image: Logs Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have sufficient access. You should also add the scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.read
```

Additionally, you must have the plug-in open for the code to run, so make sure you click its icon in the sidebar before performing any operations you expect to trigger your functions:

[image: Add on icon, circled]

Comment: This doesn't seem do it unfortunately. Also, the code in the question does not interact with any events - it only logs for now, so I think permissions is not the issue here - or am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you check your console.log output? From the GAS editor or from the [Google Developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query)?

Comment: From the Developer Console - there I see logs when I trigger from Gmail, but nothing at all for Calendar. Additionally, I can see lines in the cloud editor "Executions" tab - for Gmail, but nothing there for Calendar either

Comment: Are you creating and updating events on your calendar?

Comment: Yes - opening existing, creating, updating. (I added some screenshots of available troubleshooting tools)

Comment: Quite certain this is not a mistake in my setup. I carefully followed the guide from scratch in my private Google account (before I was using my employer's), same exact results.

Comment: Also it doesn't show in list of add-ons [Calendar Settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings), but it does for [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/addons)

Comment: Permissions are an issue - the events won't fire (and hence your handler functions will NOT be invoked) if you don't have the appropriate permissions. So you will have to change the `calendar.currentEventAccess` property and add the appropriate scopes in the manifest as the documentation recommends.